# Free jQGrid dateformatter and reuse fulldata from grid

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jqgrid, date-formatting, free-jqgrid

I've problem with date-formatted columns and datepicker as editor  in Free jQgrid
I defined a grid with some date-formatted columns and have Java-Date-objects in my data.

```
colModel:[ 
    {name:"reminderFrom",       label:"Reminder", 
    formatter:"date",  
    formatoptions:{srcformat:'ISO8601Long', newformat:'d.m.Y'},

    editoptions:{size:20, dataInit:function(el)
    {$(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy'});}, 

defaultValue: function($this) { return this.value; }},},
        ....
        ],
```

When I read the whole grid-data

```
   var fulldata = g.jqGrid('getRowData');

   manipulate it (not the datestrings!) and then want to reuse it in the grid

    g.jqGrid('setGridParam',  {datatype: 'local',  data: fulldata });  
    g.trigger("reloadGrid");
    g.jqGrid('setGridParam',  { datatype: "json"});
```

the dates will change.
How can I reformat the datestrings for reuse in the grid with dateformatter?

Comment: What is your result?

Comment: It changes every time depending on the date-string. For example 01.09.2017 becomes 28.08.2015 and then (do it again)  27.08.2010 ... The problem seems to be the dateformater with src= 'ISO8601Long' - 
I think it should be 'd.m.Y' only for the reload.

Comment: Please include always **the version** of jqGrid (or free jqGrid), which you use. Moreover, you write about "Java-Date-objects" without including any **test data** returned from the server. You can see JSON/XML data returned from the server in Network tab of Developer Tools of Chrome/IE (press F12 to start). Additionally, it's important to understand, that the format of date format in `newformat` have to be PHP date format and `dateFormat` of jQuery UI depends on the version of jQuery UI, which you use (`"dd.mm.yy"` for new jQuery UI or `"dd.MM.yyyy"` for old versions). Which jQuery UI you use?

Comment: The problem maybe here is that you get the data with getRowData method. Please check the date format of the array ahter get it  - i.e in the variable `fulldata`. The format of the date field is maybe not the same as of the initial one when you create the grid

Comment: Versions are:
jquery.ui 1.12.1
jquery 3.1.1
jqgrid 4.13.7
The problem is, that I get the displayed datestring in the array from getRowData-and use this in setRowData. But the column expects "ISO8601Long" as input. So 
I need a solution to reformat the 'd.m.Y'-String to "ISO8601Long" 
or tell the column that it should use "d.m.Y" as input 
or tell the grid that ist should give me an "ISO8601Long" String. 

I've also the millis (in a hidden column) and tried it with JavaScript.Date.toISOString(),but that didn't work.

Comment: @AndreasJust: 1) please use `@Oleg` in the comment if you see comments from other people above (I didn't get notification and opened your answer by chance). 2) could you post more full fragment of code? The current code seems be very strange. Which `datatype` has the grid? How you fill the grid with data? If the source of `reminderFrom` has other format as 
 `srcformat:'ISO8601Long'` then I see no sense to use `srcformat:'ISO8601Long'`. You should just use the value of `srcformat` which corresponds the format of input data. I repeat my previous question for the **test input data**.

Comment: @AndreasJust: It would be mostly easy if you post the URL with the demo (jsfiddle demo for example), which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Oleg
I know jsfiddle, but I'm not able to build a sample...

Here's some pseudo code - the application is based on struts and works with ajax and json

Java - Serverside:

```
class MyDataBO {
  private String myKey;
  private java.util.Date myDate;
  //...setter/getter
}

class MyGridAction {
  List< MyDataBO> gridDataList;


  public String prepareList(){
     //fill the list with MyDataBO
     return SHOW;  //struts based
  }

  public List< MyDataBO> getGridDataList() {
    return gridDataList;
  }
}
```

JSP -Clientside

```
<table id="grid"></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        url:    "MyGridAction.getGridDataList",
        jsonReader: {root: "gridDataList"},
        colModel:[
            {name:"myKey",  label:"key", key:true},
            {name:"myDate", label:"date", formatter:"date", formatoptions:{srcformat:'ISO8601Long', newformat:'d.m.Y'}
            ]
 });

</script>
```

The problem occurs here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var g = jQuery("#grid");

    var fulldata = g.jqGrid('getRowData');

    // do some work on the array

    g.jqGrid('setGridParam',  {datatype: 'local',  data: fulldata });  
    g.trigger("reloadGrid");
    g.jqGrid('setGridParam',  { datatype: "json"});                    
</script>
```

After reloadGrid the date changes...

Comment: I've choosen another way - detach all rows, put them in an array, manipulate this (order and some flags in the object) and attach them again.